# Is having a buffer per mesh in a model optimal?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, buffer

I used to assume binding vertices to be a bigger deal than binding shaders and textures, but now I've learned it's the opposite. So I'm reconfiguring my drawing. Basically:

Is it optimal to draw multiple meshes in a model with one buffer per model? Or is there an alternate solution to bind fewer bigger buffers? (I used to combine all the meshes into one big buffer and simply call the offset, but now this means I bind unnecessary vertices, as those may be bound now but used later).

By optimal I mean for CPU, GPU, and driver transfer speeds.

Comment: "*now this means I bind unnecessary vertices, as those may be bound way later*" What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, of course, is "it depends" and varies on GPU, driver, and your application requirements.

Binding can be a very lightweight operation (akin to just setting a pointer), or might require transferring data from host (CPU) memory to the GPU — it largely depends on resource usage and residency in GPU memory.  For example, if you have lots of static geometry that fits into GPU memory along with all of your other graphics resources (e.g., textures, element arrays, etc.), then a large buffer is likely better as you can initialize it once, and the driver will rapidly figure out it's supposed to stay resident.

Conversely, if you use lots of different resources for each object (e.g., switching lots of textures) all of whom can't be resident in the GPU simultaneously, then using smaller buffers might be better, since it provides the driver more options for reclaiming memory through eviction.  The other side of that coin, however, is it can cause memory fragmentation, and could potentially waste some memory (although if you're concerned with this, you don't need this question answered).

The best advice I can provide is that if you need to update the data in buffers from the CPU, try to only update the region of the buffer that's affected by those changes.  Use something like `glBufferSubData` and only update the region(s) you need (and sensibly; for example, if you need to update two 1K chunks separated by a couple of bytes, do that all in one operation).  And try to avoid using `glMapBuffer` and friends on discrete memory GPU systems.  That operation can require lots of data copying from and to the GPU; it's less impactful on integrated-memory GPU systems (although even that's not a concrete rule — buffers might be reformatted for more optimal memory operations behind the scenes).

The most sage advice is: make it right, then make it fast (and only if it's not fast enough).

Comment: Though I agree with most of your answer, the recommendation against `glMapBuffer` is incorrect to the best of my knowledge. First, using it for updating a buffer saves on copying between user-space and driver memory. Second, the general wisdom for achieving the highest throughput data streaming, on latest hardware, is to use `glMapBufferRange` with `GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT`.

Comment: @ybungalobill: On the latest hardware, you use persistent mapped buffers.

Comment: Hmm well is there a way to write to memory in one big chunk and then segment that as separate buffers?

Comment: @KarimAbdelHamid: Just use one large buffer object (you can leave gaps!) and adjust the offsets to your vertex attributes as required, so as to select just slices of the buffer for the actual drawing.

Comment: @ybungalobill Your premise is very system and implementation dependent, which means neither of us can be globally correct (and [here are some performance results](http://www.bfilipek.com/2015/01/persistent-mapped-buffers-benchmark.html) showing that point).  It's virtually impossible to know how (in every instance) the memory returned from `glMapBuffer*` is managed by the driver; `glBufferSubData` and friends are more explicit which makes the driver's job simpler (at least on the drivers I've worked on).  In the end, though, they're all sending data through that tiny straw to the GPU.

Comment: @datenwolf doesn't that imply binding unused data?

Comment: @KarimAbdelHamid: So? As long as you don't actively read or write from it, that data has zero impact on the rest of the programs behaviour in time. In other words: *It doesn't matter!*